# How can I copy many files of a certain type from many subfolders using Python?

Tags: python

I need to copy multiple .mp4 and .CR2 files from about a dozen subfolders. I have tried multiple variations of code and want to start from the beginning.

```
import os
import shutil
#os.chdir('C:\\')

dir_src = 'D:\\Users\\Tibi\\Pictures'
dir_dst = 'D:\\test'

#while True:
#    try:
#        for folder in os.walk(dir_src):
#            print(folder)
#            for filename in os.listdir(dir_src):
#                if filename.endswith('.CR2'):
#                    shutil.copy(dir_src + '\\' + filename, dir_dst)
#                print(filename)
#    except UnicodeEncodeError:
#        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>File %s was Skipped!<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" %filename)
import pathlib
import glob

dir_src = pathlib.Path('D:\\Users\\Tibi\\Pictures\\Move')
dir_dst = pathlib.Path('D:\test')

for file in dir_src.rglob('*.CR2'):
    shutil.copy(dir_src + '\\' + file, dir_dst)
    print("Current File is: %s" % file)
```

I have tried the code that was commented out without the code underneath it.

Comment: Show us the variations you have tried. What do you mean start from the beginning? The more info you can give us the better. What does the directory structure look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want, but it does assume that no files will have the same name:

```
import os
import shutil

source_dir = r"/Users/ThatOtherBatman/Foo/"
target_dir = r"/Users/ThatOtherBatman/Bar/"
extensions = (".mp4", ".cr2")

for directory, _, file_names in os.walk(source_dir):
    for file_name in file_names:
        if file_name.lower().endswith(extensions):
            source_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
            target_path = os.path.join(target_dir, file_name)
            print("Moving {} to {}".format(file_name, target_dir))
            shutil.copy(source_path, target_dir)
```

`os.walk` is what you want to use to search recursively through a directory. Then just check if the file extension is in the extensions that you want, and copy the file if it is.

Comment: I changed the source and target and it didn't work.  It paused for a second and quit with no output nor any changes in the target folder.

Comment: Really? Can you try it again with the `print` statement?

Comment: I added 3 different print lines ("Hello", "Hello World", and Hello World2", respectively) in each part of the loop (immediately after both for loops and after the if statement) and added the print statement in your line of code. 
The output was:
Hello
Hello World
Hello
Hello

Comment: I went through and double checked the code and had the incorrect source directory.  Once I fixed it, it worked fine.  I also removed the '.lower()' command because CR2 is supposed to be uppercase!  Thanks for helping me! I really apprecaite this!